# DXL Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, ibm-doors

Good afternoon,

I am currently trying to rework a filter for our DOORS program that uses Regular Expressions

I don't think the RegEx builder code works for DOORS that i use.
What I am trying to have it do is search the module for the word <<Testing>>

It would show only those that do not match this exactly.
For example:

<<Testing>> = correct

- [a-z]<<Testing>>[a-z] = incorrect (must have a space before and after)

These are incorrect because there is a space between the << | >>

- < <Testing>> (space between the first brackets)
- << Testing>> (space between brackets and beginning of word)
- <<Testing >> (space between brackets and end of word)
- <<Testing> > (space between end brackets)

These are incorrect because it is missing a < | >

- <Testing>> (missing bracket in front)
- <<Testing> (missing bracket at end)

basically if it doesn't match <<Testing>> it will show up in the filter

The RegEx code I created using a program was able to generate the pattern and gave me this

- "\b(?:<{2}Figure>{2}|<.{2}[a-z]{5}.{2}>)\b"

I tried testing it in the filter but it doesn't display anything. What am I doing wrong? I'm starting to turn grey in my beard

I'm assuming that this RegEx wont work in DOORS but I could be wrong, I'm not the greatest at creating RegEx atm

Comment: Without lookarounds, its just this `<<[a-zA-Z>>`

Comment: Try `\s<<[a-zA-Z]+>>\s` if you want spaces before and after

Comment: Do not use word boundary before and after non-word chars. You seem to want to match a string starting with `<<` then having letters and then `>>`. Try `^<<[A-Za-z]+>>$`. If you need to make sure there are whitespace chars or start/end of string on each end, use ``(?<!\S)<<[A-Za-z]+>>(?!\S)``

Comment: and yes, DXL does not work with complex RegEx expressions. The DXL manual at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQBZ_9.6.1/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/dxl_reference_manual.pdf, Chapter 11, Regular expressions mentions most of those features that work, but some work silently without explicit reference. So, word boundaries (\b) work. Omit capture (?:) does not. Multipliers ({2}) don't, use repetitions instead (<< instead of <{2}). Also, your regexp is quite strange, perhaps tell us in words what you want to test for.